# TextFlow vs TextArea, layout problems; why is TextFlow messing it where TextArea does not?

Tags: java, layout, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Here is the original fxml file (imports omitted for brevity):

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:id="pane"
    fx:controller="com.github.parboiled1.grappa.debugger.mainwindow.MainWindowUi">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                <!-- INJECTION -->
                <MenuItem fx:id="loadInput" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Load file" onAction="#loadFileEvent"/>
                <MenuItem fx:id="parse" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Parse" onAction="#parseEvent"/>
                <MenuItem fx:id="closeButton" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    text="Close" onAction="#closeWindowEvent"/>
            </Menu>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0"
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL">
                <TreeView fx:id="traceTree" prefHeight="200.0"
                    prefWidth="200.0" style="font-family: monospace"/>
                <TextArea fx:id="traceDetail" editable="false"
                    prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                    style="-fx-font-family: monospace"/>
            </SplitPane>
            <!-- HERE -->
            <TextArea fx:id="inputText" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"/>
        </SplitPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I want to perform text highlighting of *part* of the text in what is for now a `TextArea` with an `fx:id` of `inputText`. For this, I have been recommended to use a `TextFlow` instead of a `TextArea`. "XML comment": `HERE`.

I already have, at "XML comment" `INJECTION`, the means to fill the contents of `inputText` with the contents of a (text) file. This works fine with a `TextArea`.

Now, what I have done: I just replaced `TextArea` with `TextFlow`, adapted the code, and that's it. Nothing else.

And the layout gets messed up when I load a decently large text file. Before I load it, the layout is just fine:

[image: Before load]

Now I try and load a text file which is long enough so that it doesn't fit into the `TextFlow` as it is, and... This is what I get:

[image]

I have no such problem when using a `TextArea`. The latter will automatically "insert" (if that's the correct word) vertical and horizontal scrollbars, and will leave my `MenuBar` intact, thank you very much.

But a `TextArea` won't allow me to highlight only part of the text... Therefore I need a `TextFlow`.

How do I make a `TextFlow` behave, "layout-wise", as a `TextArea`?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `TextFlow` in a `ScrollPane`?

Comment: @James_D uhm... No. I'll try...

Comment: @James_D I kind of had this intuition but... You did it again! Wrapping in a `ScrollPane` did the trick... Should you make this an answer, I'll accept it, along with, if you have it, an explanation of why `TextArea` does not need it! I really suck badly at anything GUI, as you can see :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TextArea` implements its own scrollbars, allocating space for them and making them visible automatically when they are required. `TextFlow` is really just a plain layout manager, and doesn't do this. To put scroll bars on the `TextFlow` when they are needed, just wrap the `TextFlow` in a `ScrollPane`:

```
<ScrollPane>
    <TextFlow fx:id="inputText" ... />
</ScrollPane>
```

You actually have much more control over the scrollbars in this situation. For example, you can do

```
<ScrollPane fitToWidth="true">
```

and then the content (the `TextFlow` in this case) will have its width set to the width of the scroll pane (so there will never be horizontal scroll bars, only vertical ones). The [`ScrollPane` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) list all the properties, of course.

Comment: I've discussed the layouting and editing http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/12/27/displaying-and-editing-large-styled-texts/